# Delete a node (key) from an infinite json object dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, recursion

I am working with an infinite depth json object. The structure kinda look like this

```
{
    "RECORDS": [
        {
            "Idx": 1,
            "Child": [
                {
                    "Hidden": "0",
                    "Node_Type": "SD",
                    "Idx": 4,
                    "Parent_Idx": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Idx": 2,
            "Child": [
                {
                    "Idx": 5,
                    "Node_Type": "MENU",
                    "Parent_Idx": 2,
                    "Child": [
                        {
                            "Idx": 6,
                            "Node_Type": "SD",
                            "Parent_Idx": 5
                        }
                        {
                            ...
                            ...

                            "Child": ...
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Idx": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I'm trying to delete a single node from this nested object dynamically.

```
jsonObj.forEach(deleteJsonRecursively);

function deleteJsonRecursively(item, index){
    if (item.Idx == rowId) {
        console.log(delete item); // This returns false.
    }
    else {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty('Child')) {
            item.Child.forEach(deleteJsonRecursively);
        }
    }
}
```

I know it's invalid to delete the item itself. But that's the question, how can I remove that particular node from my jsonObj. I mean is there any way I can do it dynamically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What should it log if you `delete item` twice and only log the second try? Please post the desired output and a complete minimal example of what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Array.splice to remove elements from array, refer to the follow code:

```
function deleteJsonRecursively( arr ) {
    for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++ ) {
        var item = arr[i];
        if( item.Idx == rowId ) {
           arr.splice(i,1); // remove here
           i --; // arr.length changed after arr.splice 
        } else if( item.hasOwnProperty('Child') ) {
           deleteJsonRecursively(item.Child);
        }
    }
}
deleteJsonRecursively(jsonObj.RECORDS);
```